# SSRS dataset not refreshed after changing MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, ssrs-2008

SSRS dataset not refreshed after changing MySQL stored procedure.

I created an SSRS report in which the dataset gets data from MySQL stored procedure. In this scenario the output is generated correctly and so is the report.

Later I modify some content in the stored procedure. I run the stored proc in query designer. In query designer it gives the correct output.

But when going to report if I see the report in preview tab it gives old values. Changed are not coming in presenting report.

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Close and open Business Intelligence Studio.

Answer (score 15):

Try deleting the MySolution\MyProject\MyRDL.data file -- BIDS caches fairly aggressively.

Comment: I spent the half day in this, you saved the second half ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in Visual Studio i think it happens to me as well. Usually closing the report in Visual studio and reopening helps.

Answer (score 1):

the report may be cached on BIDS for a few moments.

re-open it and it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I TESTED IN VS2012

**Note :** 
**1.  Go to your Report designer
2. Remember(or copy somewhere) your (A) Data Source Name  and (B) Data Sets Name**

Now Step 1:
In the Project Solution Explore Delete the Data Set (same name as in Note(A) Data Source Name 
) Don't Worry Nothing will bad on your report :)
Step 2: 
open the Report data  tool of your report
Step 3: 
 * Select dataSet --> Right Click ----> Select DataSet Properties
 * In " data source" click on NEW button---->Next---->
 * Select your table/sp/views/-----> **Put the Data set Name as:(Note 2. Remember your (A) Data Source Name )**

- Now Finish...  :) now you can get your Newly added field in SP

NOTE : ONLY REMEMBER your old data source and dataset name

Thanks, enjoy ...
Regards,
SRSahoo@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure it's the report and not you.

I switched the sorting fields in the dataset and they weren't changing in the report preview because I didn't change the Grouping.